# Let $V$=$P(R)$, and for $j \geqslant 1$ define $T_j(f(x))$=$f^{(j)}(x)$,where $f^{j}(x)$ is the $j^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> [image]

For this problem, can I construct a zero transformation and do the regular step of proving linear independence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $ \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} c_jT_j=0$ then $ \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} c_jf^{(j)}(x)=0$ for every $x$ and every $f \in P(\mathbb R)$. Put $f(x)=x$ to get $c_1=0$. Then put $f(x)=x^{2}$ to get $c_2=0$, and so on.

Comment: so for this problem, do we have to explain why we construct a zero transformation?

Comment: $L(V)$ is a vector space. Its zero element is the zero transformation. @xyz12354